# Access parent data context in Template rendered function in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have the following parent template:

```
<template name="parentTempl">
    {{#each child}}
       {{> childTempl}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

I want to access the parent data context in `childTempl`:

```
Template.childTempl.rendered = function() {
    console.log(this.parent.data); // ?
};
```

How can I do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_parentdata?

Comment: Yes. The problem is, when I use `Template.parentData(1)._id` in my `rendered` function, I get this error: `Error: There is no current view`.

Comment: That's odd, I just tested it and it seems to work. What does this.view or Blaze.currentView return inside the rendered function?

Comment: Sorry for that. It works fine, I put `Template.parentData(1)._id` in the wrong context. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great! :) I'm just going to break this out as an answer for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `Template.parentData(n)` to access the parent context inside any template helper or rendered callback. See the docs [here](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html). Internally, all it does is call the Blaze getView method for the parent view until it hits the desired parent context (as defined by n).

Comment: How would this be done in an event?  Template.hello.events()?